# SUMIF sometimes not summing when criteria is met

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

SUMIF is not summing some of the cells despite the logic being met. For example, cell B9 on sheet 3 should result in 25, but it is coming back with 0.

I've tried
`sumif(Sheet2!$B26:$O26, "*MW*", Sheet2!$B9:$O9)` `sumif(Sheet2!$B26:$O26, "*"&B$1&"*", Sheet2!$B9:$O9)` and `sumif(Sheet2!$B26:$O26, "*"&B$1&"*", Sheet2!$B9:$O9)+sumif(Sheet2!$B26:$O26, "B$1", Sheet2!$B9:$O9)` and nothing is giving me the proper results.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdMC-8aH8W3ngwS7zmu97lbPOWZV2Ipk70ZGqnftx3w/edit?usp=sharing)

Ideally I would like this to work with Sheet 1 formatted the way that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your SUMIF function is working properly.  The problem is that there is no number in `Sheet2!B9` to SUM because `"25"` is not the number `25`

#### Your formula in `Sheet2!B9`

```
# where Sheet1!B10="25 MW" 

=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!B10),
    Sheet1!B10,
    REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B10,
                 "[^\d]+", "")
    )

="25"    # ISNUMBER("25")=FALSE
```

If you want to coerce a number that is a text string to a number, you can attempt a mathematical calculation that doesn't change the number.  e.g. divide by 1

```
# where Sheet1!B10="25 MW" 

=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!B10),
    Sheet1!B10,
    REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B10,
                 "[^\d]+", "")/1
    )

=25    # ISNUMBER(25)=TRUE
```